# Custom Angular directive with template won't run in node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, directive

I have worked a few Angular projects, but am a little new to node. I have a custom directive that displays summary statistics about data, `<summary-stats></summary-stats>`. The directive works fine when I'm developing the front end using Gulp and Browser Sync, but when I build all of the files and run `node server.js`, my custom directives cause the browser to lag out. I believe that it's due to including a `templateUrl` in the directive.

Is there something I need to do to include templates specified by `templateUrl` so that node will serve up the HTML files?

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('summaryStats', function(scatterService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/summaryStats/summaryStats.html',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {

            function update(data) {
                scope.lowCost = data.xMin;
                scope.highCost = data.xMax;
                scope.avgCost = data.avgCost;
                scope.lowTime = data.yMin;
                scope.highTime = data.yMax;
                scope.avgTime = data.avgTime;
                scope.topTechs = data.topTechs;
            }

            scope.$watch(function() { return scatterService.getModel(); }, function(newVal) {
                update(newVal);
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.headers['if-none-match'] = 'no-match-for-this';
  next();    
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(methodOverride());

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that that my Gulp build task wasn't inserting the templates into the distribution folder. This problem was solved by placing a `static` folder that housed my HTML files, and building that into my distribution folder with Gulp.